# Size of a GET Request Response

Tags: get, request, response, gsm, sim900

I'm developing a GSM/GPRS application that will report some values each 10 seconds. The SIM that I have to work has only 15MB of data available each month. I'm using a SIM900 GSM chips for your reference.

They way I'm reaching the server is via a GET method like this

```
 www.genericserver.com/local.php?method=GET&var1=value1&var2=value2
```

So local.php is the landing point and where the values are inserted to the Database.

I'm trying to dimension how many byes of data does the GET method consumes when invoking the method so I can know how many REQUEST/RESPOND action can I perform with 15MB of data before consume it all.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your local.php return just a few bytes like `OK` or `fail`, as cellular networks count both download and upload. It is important that the response of page is kept as small as possible, I would even strip down the html header and tags and just send plain text. `OK` or `Fail`

You may use atool like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-traffic-recording) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff packets on your pc to get an estimate.

### UPDATE

If in case you don't use both you may get help from chrome.

1. Open chrome
2. start inspector by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
3. select the network tab
4. check the data transferred value

Here is an example how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks dmsherazi for your suggestion. I will try taking this measurement and place it here. Your recommendation for having short replies is a good technique for saving data, I will use it. What would you think a short GET request/response size should have? So when I take the mesurements I can have a reference value to compare